# Why pushing more than 3 MPLS headers on a packet results in the packet not being forwarded?

Tags: openvswitch

MPLS header stacks are limited to size 3. Pushing more than 3 MPLS headers on a packet results in the packet not being forwarded in Open vSwitch.

```
sudo mn --topo single,2 --switch ovsk
mininet> h1 ping h2
```

Installed a minimal set of flow entries on s1:

```
sudo ovs-ofctl -O OpenFlow13 add-flow s1 in_port=1,actions=push_mpls:0x8847,push_mpls:0x8847,push_mpls:0x8847,push_mpls:0x8847,output:2
sudo ovs-ofctl -O OpenFlow13 add-flow s1 in_port=2,actions=push_mpls:0x8847,push_mpls:0x8847,push_mpls:0x8847,push_mpls:0x8847,output:1
```

Flow entries are correctly matched. 
`sudo ovs-ofctl -O OpenFlow13 dump-flows s1 | grep -o "n_packets=\w*"`
Yet no packets leave s1 confirmed by
`sudo tcpdump -ni s1-eth2`

Any explanation will be appreciated

Comment: Duplicate?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116527/why-pushing-more-than-3-mpls-headers-on-a-packet-results-in-the-packet-not-being

Comment: This does not have any component of Ryu controller.

Comment: My version works for upto 2 headers and uses OvS 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

For version 2.4.0 lib/flow.h contains a variable called FLOW_MAX_MPLS_LABELS which defines the maximum number of mpls supported in a stack. The value is set to 3

https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/v2.4.0/lib/flow.h

```
#define FLOW_MAX_MPLS_LABELS 3
```

For later version you should check but they will probably take a similar approach, limiting to 3 mpls in the code.